# правильно ли пишу php скрипт для обработки ajax запросов?

Tags: php, ajax

Добрый вечер господа!

есть файл `ajax.php`, к которому будут поступать разные ajax запросы. Все запросы будут иметь обязательный параметр `action`, от которого будет понятно, какой действие выполнять.

В `ajax.php` пишу словия:

```
if($_POST["action"] == "add") {
 ...
}

if($_POST["action"] == "delete") {
 ...
}

...
```

в этой файле также написал такую функцию:

```
   function _error($err = false) {
        $err = array("error" => ($err ? $err : "error"));
        echo json_encode($err);
        die();
    }


   function _secusses($msg= false) {
        $msg= array("secusses_answer" => ($msg? $msg: ""));
        echo json_encode($msg);
        die();
    }
```

которую вызываю с тех случаях, которые от клиента пришли некорректные данные, либо произошли какие-то ошибки добавления данных или удаления, и возвращаю текст ошибки.

Вопрос в том, что можно ли использовать в таком случае die() ? Или как лучше делать, что бы вернуть ошибку клиенту, и не продолжать выполнение кода?

Например, где это используется:

```
if($_POST["action"] == "sendseckey") {
    if(isset($_POST["phone"]) && !empty($_POST["phone"])) {
        if($USER->IsAuthorized()) {

            $u = new Unril;
            $res = $u->sendSecKeyByPhone($_POST["phone"]);
            if($res) {
                $user = new Core\CUser;
                $user->Update($USER->ID(), array(
                    "PHONE" => htmlspecialcharsbx($_POST["phone"])
                ));
                _secusses();
            } else {
                _error("Телефон не найден в системе");
            }
        } else {
            _error("Вы не авторизованы на сайте");
        }

    } else {
        _error("Некорректный телефон");
    }
}
```

Вопрос в том, что можно ли так использовать такие функции как _error() и _secusses() ?

Или как грамотнее писать?

Comment: `_secusses` - это от success? Вместо `die` можно `exit`. Не вижу проблем с вашими функциями.

Comment: Функции эти можно использовать, почему нет. А вот от большой вложенности if лучше избавляться.